# How to go to content div with window.location.href for a iframe from document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I want to jump to the particular content with `window.location.href = id` but it is working for normal page, but does not work  within `iframe`

**Question:**  how can I jump to that particular content within `iframe`

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/3289/

**below is full code:**

```js
var $iframe = $('#iframe');
$iframe.ready(function() {
    $iframe.contents().find("body").append(
       
       `<div id="content1"> CONTENT 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam laborum, dolore iusto expedita accusamus, minima temporibus cum, doloremque ullam non incidunt quam earum ducimus iure sapiente dicta. Laborum, consequuntur, rerum! <hr/></div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div id="content2"> CONTENT 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam laborum, dolore iusto expedita accusamus, minima temporibus cum, doloremque ullam non incidunt quam earum ducimus iure sapiente dicta. Laborum, consequuntur, rerum! <hr/></div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div id="content3"> CONTENT 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam laborum, dolore iusto expedita accusamus, minima temporibus cum, doloremque ullam non incidunt quam earum ducimus iure sapiente dicta. Laborum, consequuntur, rerum! <hr/></div>
  
  <br>
   
  <div id="content4"> CONTENT 4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam laborum, dolore iusto expedita accusamus, minima temporibus cum, doloremque ullam non incidunt quam earum ducimus iure sapiente dicta. Laborum, consequuntur, rerum! <hr/></div>
 
 <br>` );
 
 
 // above iframe creation code 
 
 //actual code
 var index = 0;
 
 $('#loopcontent').on('click',function(){
    index++;
    if(index > 4) index = 0;
    console.log('content id','#content'+index);
    window.location.href = '#content'+index;
 });
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

<button id="loopcontent">
  go to content
</button>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the location on **your** window.

```
window.location.href = '#content'+index;
```

An IFrame has [its own window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow), you need to set the location there:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.location.hash = 'content'+index;
```

Also, if the IFrame src is from another ["Origin"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), you won't be able to access its content and this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll desired div into view with javascript like this:

```
 $('#loopcontent').on('click',function(){
    index++;
    if(index > 4) index = 1;
    $iframe_window = $iframe.contents();
    var $div = $iframe_window.find('#content'+index);
    $iframe_window.find('body').scrollTop($div.offset().top);
 });
```

See jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vj2thr5f/)